# perl script to connect to mysql server port 3307

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to connect to a mysql server which is running at port 3307. How do I connect to the server? I do not see any other way to specify port. I am using like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mysql;

$host = "localhost";
$database = "abc";
$tablename = "def";
$user = "uuu";
$pw = "ppp";


$connect = Mysql->connect($host, $database, $user, $pw) or die "Cannot connect to MySQL server\n";
```

I want to use MySQL package and not DBI.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use DBD DBI ? They are the standard on perl...

Comment: -1:  No, you want to use DBI.  Really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mistaken.  You want to use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) and not Mysql.  The Mysql module became obsolete 12 years ago, when it was replaced with a compatibility module that's just a wrapper around DBI.  Even the compatibility module has been removed from the current distribution; you have to install an old [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/) just to get it (it last shipped in [DBD-mysql 3.0008](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql-3.0008/), released back in 2006).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $host = "localhost";
my $database = "abc";
my $port = 3307;
my $tablename = "def";
my $user = "uuu";
my $pw = "ppp";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host;port=$port",
                       $user, $pw)
  or die "Cannot connect to MySQL server\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying host like `localhost:3307`

Answer (score 0):

For me...Following seems to be working ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $host = "rajeshk-W7";
my $database = "rajesh";
my $port = 3307;
my $tablename = "def";
my $user = "rajesh";
my $pw = "rajesh123";
#my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:rajesh:rajeshk-W7","rajesh","rajesh123") or die "Cannot connect to MySQL server\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host",$user, $pw) or die "Cannot connect to MySQL server\n";
```

where i dint mentioned port. When i add port, its unable to connect.